# How do I condense this into a good for loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, rename

Basically, how do you turn this into an efficient for loop?  I need to insert a space in filenames in folders, preferably subfolders too; between any number and any letter after it, not before it, leaving everything else in the filename alone, including visible file extensions.  The number is not always on the same token.  This would go from A-Z.

```
:trim-r
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CD %workdir%
PUSHD "%workdir%"
for /r %workdir% %%j in (*.*) do (
set filename=%%~nj
set filename=!filename:0a=0 a!
set filename=!filename:1a=1 a!
set filename=!filename:2a=2 a!
set filename=!filename:3a=3 a!
set filename=!filename:4a=4 a!
set filename=!filename:5a=5 a!
set filename=!filename:6a=6 a!
set filename=!filename:7a=7 a!
set filename=!filename:8a=8 a!
set filename=!filename:9a=9 a!
set filename=!filename:0b=0 b!
set filename=!filename:1b=1 b!
set filename=!filename:2b=2 b!
set filename=!filename:3b=3 b!
set filename=!filename:4b=4 b!
set filename=!filename:5b=5 b!
set filename=!filename:6b=6 b!
set filename=!filename:7b=7 b!
set filename=!filename:8b=8 b!
set filename=!filename:9b=9 b!
set filename=!filename:0c=0 c!
set filename=!filename:1c=1 c!
set filename=!filename:2c=2 c!
set filename=!filename:3c=3 c!
set filename=!filename:4c=4 c!
set filename=!filename:5c=5 c!
set filename=!filename:6c=6 c!
set filename=!filename:7c=7 c!
set filename=!filename:8c=8 c!
set filename=!filename:9c=9 c!
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nj" ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj"
)
endlocal
popd
EXIT /B
```

Comment: There is no need to use `/r %workdir%` after you have done `pushd "%workdir%". You can simply use `/r` without a path.

Comment: Good note, thanks dbenham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code don't match your description (why "h" is changed to "a" and "w" to "c"?) and you didn't posted any example. Anyway, the code below change any `<digit><letter>` into `<digit><space><letter>`.

```
for /R %workdir% %%j in (*.*) do (
   set "filename=%%~nj"
   for /L %%n in (0,1,9) do (
      for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
         set "filename=!filename:%%n%%a=%%n %%a!"
      )
   )
   if "!filename!" neq "%%~nj" ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj"
)
```

Comment: This is a good pure batch solution. The only potential problems I see is it will convert upper case letter to lower case if it precedes a digit. Also, it will fail if the name contains `!` character.

Comment: Awesome thank you.  You're right I'll go fix the example really quick.  I put it up and changed it to abc for simplicity and forgot to change the others.

Comment: I was trying to put a code together like that previously, it looks like I was pretty close. :D

Answer (score 1):

My [jrepl.bat regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) makes this task really simple and efficient. It is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

Assuming JREPL.BAT is in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH:

```
call jren "([a-zA-Z])([0-9])" "$1 $2" /s /p "%workdir%"
```